# Using ifelse to sum numbers

Tags: r, if-statement, sum

I'm noob in coding, so i'm having a hard time finishing assignments.  i wanna get some help..

9. Using ifelse and seq commands in R, calculate the sum of numbers that are evenly divided by 6 between 1 and 1000. (The answer is not unique, but your answer should use ifelse and seq properly.)
10. Calculate the sum of numbers that are evenly divided by 3 between 1 and 1000. by for loop. Show your coding and the sum. (Answer is not unique. Any reasonable for loop will get full points.)

I know that I should use seq(6,1000,6) and seq(3,1000,3) for each, but I cannot get the answer
pls help

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, you could create a sequence between 1 to 1000 and then sum the numbers if it is divisible by 6

```
num <- seq(1,1000)
total <- sum(ifelse(num %% 6 == 0, num, 0))
total
#[1] 83166
```

For question 2, you could do :

```
total <- 0
for (i in num) {
  if(i %% 3 == 0)
     total <- total + i
}

total
#[1] 166833
```

---

There are also other ways to do this.

For question 1, you could do :

```
sum(num[num %% 6 == 0])
```

OR

```
 sum(seq(6, 1000, 6))
```

And similarly, for question 2 :

```
sum(num[num %% 3 == 0])
```

OR

```
sum(seq(3, 1000, 3))
```